# Redux-Toolkit not update state in logic section React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have problem with update state in redux-toolkit. In section html state is updated correctly but in logic section state is not updated. What i do not correctly?

```
export default function TestPage() {
  const playerState = useAppSelector(state => state.player);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    
  const setMenuVisible = () => dispatch(playerActions.setIsMenuVisible(true));
  const handleKeyUp = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    setMenuVisible();

    // STATE IS NOT UPDATED
    if (playerState.isMenuUIVisible) {
      if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        dispatch(playerActions.setIsFullscreen(false));
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    // STATE IS UPDATE CORRECTLY
    <div className={`${playerState.isMenuUIVisible ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'} transition duration-500 absolute bottom-0 h-60 w-full bg-gradient-to-b from-transparent via-neutral-900/85 to-neutral-900 flex flex-col justify-end z-0 space-y-4 pb-4`}>
      <div
        className={"mt-6 h-[1px] bg-gradient-to-r from-transparent via-[#008DD2] to-transparent w-full "}
      />
      <div className={"relative flex justify-between space-x-4 pr-4"}>
        <div
          id={'scrollChannel'}
          className={"grow overflow-y-auto h-28 space-y-8 snap-y snap-mandatory scrollbar-hide focus:outline-none"}
        >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={"mb-6 h-[1px] bg-gradient-to-r from-transparent via-[#008DD2] to-transparent w-full"}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Player Slice: In this fragment is playerSlice

```js
export const playerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "player",
  initialState: initialPlayerState,
  reducers: {
    setIsMenuVisible: (state: IPlayerState, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.isMenuUIVisible= action.payload;
    },
    setIsFullscreen: (state: IPlayerState, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.isFullscreen = action.payload;
    },
    togglePlaying: (state: IPlayerState) => {
      state.playing = !state.playing;
    },
    togglePlaying: (state: IPlayerState) => {
      state.playing = !state.playing;
    },
    toggleMuted: (state: IPlayerState) => {
      state.muted = !state.muted;
    },
  },
})

export const playerActions = playerSlice.actions
export default playerSlice.reducer
```

How to update state in logic section?

Comment: you have a closure over `playerState`, bring the `handleKeyUp` function within the `useEffect` and add `playerState.isMenuUIVisible` to the deps array so you get the latest state every re-render, otherwise you're only getting the state on first render. you should recreate `handleKeyUp` every time `isMenuUIVisible` changes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a stale closure over the selected `playerState` value from the Redux store in the `handleKeyUp` handler from the initial render cycle where the `"keyup"` event listeners are instantiated.

You can include `playerState` as a dependency so when its value changes a new copy of `handleKeyUp` can re-enclose the current value to be used in the callback.

```js
const playerState = useAppSelector(state => state.player);
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  const setMenuVisible = () => dispatch(
    playerActions.setIsMenuVisible(true)
  );

  const handleKeyUp = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    setMenuVisible();

    if (playerState.isMenuUIVisible) {
      if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        dispatch(playerActions.setIsFullscreen(false));
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  };
}, [dispatch, playerState]);
```

Or you can import the store object and access the current value in the handler. This removes `playerState` as an external dependency and you can keep the empty dependency array (*or include `dispatch` still since it's technically an external dependency, it's a stable reference and ok to include*).

```js
import { store, AppState } from '../path/to/store';

...

const playerState = useAppSelector(state => state.player);
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  const setMenuVisible = () => dispatch(
    playerActions.setIsMenuVisible(true)
  );

  const handleKeyUp = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    const playerState = (store.getState() as AppState).player;

    setMenuVisible();

    if (playerState.isMenuUIVisible) {
      if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        dispatch(playerActions.setIsFullscreen(false));
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  };
}, [dispatch]);
```